How to evaluate performance and optimize hyperparameters for clustering algorithms on a dataset with continuous labels?
I'm working on a clustering problem where my dataset's labels are continuous numerical values, not discrete categories. I'm using t-SNE and UMAP to reduce the dimensionality of my dataset's features to 2D and then visualizing the points on a scatter plot, with points colored according to their label values.
My goal is to see if the feature representations accurately reflect the variations in label values, i.e., whether points with similar label values cluster together in the 2D space. Or, specific data points do not need to be clustered together. It is only necessary to observe certain trends, where the distribution of data points moves in a regular pattern as the value of the labels increases or decreases.
I am tuning various hyperparameters of t-SNE and UMAP to achieve this. So far, I've been evaluating the results by visually inspecting the scatter plots for any patterns or trends. Here's an example of a plot I've generated:
Example of UMAP clustering result figure, for reference
Could anyone suggest methods or metrics to quantitatively assess how well the clustering performed by t-SNE and UMAP reflects the continuous nature of the labels? Any advice on how to objectively determine the best hyperparameter settings for these methods would be greatly appreciated.
If you need any further information, please let me know, thank you!

I think you would have better chances if you ask this question at crossvalidated
